# Is there any matrix with this propery?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

> Is there any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with complex entries such that $\operatorname{rank}A=2$, its eigenvalues are $\lambda,\lambda,0,0,\dots,0$ with $\lambda \neq 0$ and $X^2(X-\lambda)$ is its minimal polynomial?

My intuition is that there is not, since I can't find a specific example which satisfies these properties. However, I tried using the minimal and characteristic polynomials and also the Jordan form hoping that I could get something, but nothing came out useful in the end.

I am new to linear algebra and I am still learning, so an elementary solution (if there is one) for proving the non-existence would be much appreciated.

**Later edit** I added the condition that $X^2(X-\lambda)$ is $A's$ minimal polynomial.

Comment: As a matter of principle, if you have an edit to a question which invalidates already given answers, best to create another question since the edited question is a different question then the one initially asked

Comment: I agree with you. However, I thought they would be too similar and hence be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: If you link to your original question in your new post and explain the situation, the mods will understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a $2\times 2$ block with $X-\lambda$ as minimal polynomial and a $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ block with $X^2$ as minimal polynomial. The simplest matrix that satisfies these requirements is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 &0 &\dotsb & 0 \\
0 & \lambda &0&\dotsb & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0&\dotsb & 1 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&0&\dotsb&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
All non diagonal entries are zero, except $a_{3n}=1$.